# How to deduct amount for the time condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Table1

```
ID Salary (Monthly) perday (salary)

001 3000 100
002 1500 50
003 4500 150
```

`Salary`, `perday` columns are of datatype `float`

Table2

```
ID Date Latetime (HH:mm)

001 01/02/2012 00:15 
001 02/02/2012 00:10
001 03/02/2012 00:45 
001 04/02/2012 00:29
001 05/02/2012 01:00

002 11/03/2012 00:02 
002 12/03/2012 00:20
002 13/03/2012 00:29
002 14/03/2012 01:00


002 10/03/2012 01:30 
002 10/03/2012 02:00
```

I want to deduct the salary amount according to the count of latetime.

Condition

01 to 29 mintues late condition

- If User late on 1st time no deduction
- If user late on 2nd time 10% deduction of perday salary
- If user late on 3rd time 25% deduction of perday salary
- If user late on 4th time and above  50% deduction of perday salary

30 mintues to 1 hour late condition

- If User late on 1st time no deduction
- If user late on 2nd time 50% deduction of perday salary
- If user late on 3rd time 100% deduction of perday salary
- If user late on 4th time and above  150% deduction of perday salary

Expected Output for table2

```
         4th onwards
ID Ist 2nd 3rd  days Amount Deducted 


001 0 10 50  2 250 310
002 0 10 10 1 100   120
```

Output explanation

User 001 late for 5 times as a Count(latetime) from table2

- 1st time late for 00:15 minutes - no deduction
- 2nd time late for 00:10 minutes, so late time in between 01 to 29, so 10 % of perday salary deduction '1st time (01 to 29)
- 3rd time late for 00:45 minutes, so late time in between 30 to 01 hours, so 50 % of perday salary deduction '1st time (30 to 01)
- 4th time late for 00:29 minutes, so late time in between 01 to 29, so 50 % of perday salary deduction '2nd time (01 to 29)
- 5th time late for 01:00 minutes, so late time in between 30 to 01 hours, so 150 % of perday salary deduction '1st time (30 to 01)

How to create a query for the above conditions?

Comment: Not sure if SqlServer (T-SQL) is the best tool for this kind of work. This seems business logic decisions.

Comment: It would be easy using triggers after or before insert on table2. Do you agree? If yes then there can be an easy solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--create and populate penalty rules
create table table4( latetype int null, nthtime int null, mulfactor float null)
insert into table4 values (1,1,0) insert into table4 values (1,2,0.1)
insert into table4 values (1,3,0.25) insert into table4 values (1,4,0.5)
insert into table4 values (2,1,0) insert into table4 values (2,2,0.5)
insert into table4 values (2,3,1.0) insert into table4 values (2,4,1.5)
--create third table to populate the nthtime and latetype for table2
select x.id, date,
      (select count(*) from table2 where id=x.id and date<=x.date) as nthtime, 
      case when x.latetime<'00:30' then 1 else 2 end as latetype
into table3
from table2 x join table1 on table1.id = x.id
--select the deduction amounth per id 
select table1.id, 
       sum(table1.perday* 
       isnull(mulfactor, case when latetype = 1 then .5 else 1.5 end) )as deduction
from table3 a 
left join table4 b on a.latetype=b.latetype and a.nthtime=b.nthtime 
join table1 on table3.id = table1.id
group by table1.id
```